# Deployment Manager Failed to Update Bucket Name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I'm using the exact same template as the example [template](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-foundation-toolkit/tree/master/dm/templates/gcs_bucket).
I first deploy the template with bucket name X:

```
imports:
  - path: templates/gcs_bucket/gcs_bucket.py
    name: gcs_bucket.py

resources:
  - name: X
    type: gcs_bucket.py
    properties:
      name: X
      location: us-east1
      versioning:
        enabled: True
      labels:
        env: development
```

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments create s3-sample --config gcs_bucket.yaml
```

which runs successfully.

Next, I tried to deploy using the same template but changing the bucket name to: Y

```
imports:
  - path: templates/gcs_bucket/gcs_bucket.py
    name: gcs_bucket.py

resources:
  - name: Y
    type: gcs_bucket.py
    properties:
      name: Y
      location: us-east1
      versioning:
        enabled: True
      labels:
        env: development
```

With the update command

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments create s3-sample --config gcs_bucket.yaml
```

It failed with

```
Waiting for update [operation-1596317964460-5abd7bd3863a0-46f678bb-c6e8f7f7]...failed.                                                                                                                                                        
ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.update) Error in Operation [operation-1596317964460-5abd7bd3863a0-46f678bb-c6e8f7f7]: errors:
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
  location: /deployments/s3-sample/resources/X
  message: '{"ResourceType":"gcp-types/storage-v1:buckets","ResourceErrorCode":"403","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":403,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"XXX@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com
    does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.","reason":"forbidden"}],"message":"XXX@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com
    does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.","statusMessage":"Forbidden","requestPath":"https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/X","httpMethod":"GET","suggestion":"Consider
    granting permissions to XXX@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com"}}'
```

But the bucket Y was created successfully and the bucket X was not deleted?
What did I do wrong?
I tried the update command again after deleting the X bucket, and it worked.

Comment: Judging by the description, you are trying to create a deployment with the existing name **s3-sample** once again for the bucket **Y**. What do you actually want to achieve: 1) create two buckets **X** and **Y**; or 2) update the existing deployment **s3-sample** for the bucket **X** so that change the bucket name to **Y**?

Comment: Is the account you use granted the  `storage.admin` IAM role?

Comment: @mebius99 2) I want to update the bucket name X to Y.

Comment: I believe this is because the service account being used by deployment manager simply does not have sufficient permissions to delete buckets. renaming a bucket is simply creating a new bucket, moving the contents and deleting the old one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cloud Storage, objects are **immutable**, which means that an uploaded or created object cannot change through its storage lifetime.  This means that buckets **can't be renamed**.

[Cloud Storage > Doc > Bucket naming guidelines > Bucket name requirements](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-buckets#requirements):

> - A **bucket name** can only be **assigned during creation**. You **cannot change the name** of an existing bucket. Instead, you should create a new bucket with the desired name and move the contents from
>   the old bucket to the new bucket. See [Moving and Renaming
>   Buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets) for a
>   step-by-step guide.

[Cloud Storage > Doc > Moving and renaming buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets):

> When you create a bucket, you **permanently define its name**.
> However, you can effectively move or rename your bucket:
>
> - If there is no data in your old bucket, delete the bucket and create another bucket with a new name.

According to the error message, the second deployment does not have problems with the creation of a new bucket **Y**, but lacks permissions on the previously created bucket **X**.

By default the Google APIs Service Agent account used by Deployment Manager is granted the `Project Editor` role:

```
CloudShell:$ gcloud projects get-iam-policy my-project --flatten="bindings[].members" --format='table(bindings.role)' --filter="bindings.members:111111111111@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com"
  ROLE
  roles/editor
CloudShell:$ gcloud iam roles describe roles/editor | grep storage.buckets
- storage.buckets.create
- storage.buckets.delete
- storage.buckets.list
```

As you can see, the `Project Editor` role includes the `create` and `delete` permissions on buckets, but not the `get`. That is why the first deployment goes Ok and creates a new bucket **X**. But the second deployment fails because it can't delete the previous bucket **X**, whereas it succeeds in creation of the new bucket **Y**. This also explains why the second deployment succeeds when you delete the bucket **X** manually.

To get this working, you should follow the documentation on the cloud-foundation-toolkit.
[GitHub > GoogleCloudPlatform / cloud-foundation-toolkit > Google Cloud Storage Bucket](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-foundation-toolkit/tree/master/dm/templates/gcs_bucket#google-cloud-storage-bucket):

> Prerequisites
>
> - Grant the `storage.admin` IAM role to the Deployment Manager service account

The `Storage Admin` role includes all `storage.buckets.*` roles, including `get`.
[Cloud IAM > Doc > Understanding roles > Predefined roles > Cloud Storage roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-storage-roles):
[image: 20200803 - Deployment Manager failed to update bucket name - Cloud_Storage_Roles]